# Does MapServer allow to set up empty tiles as a return of a webapp request for data outside of the layer mask in MapServer?

Tags: mapserver, masking, mapcache

Is it possible to set up empty tiles as a return for webapp request of a data outside of the layer mask in MapServer ?

I have a MapServer-based webapp with a layer that uses a mask option to limit layer extent. While requesting tiles outside of the mask I am receiving an error in app:
[image]

and MapServer is responding with:

> failed to link tile data/WebMercator/002/111.png to ../../../blanks/00000000.png: Permission denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error can be silenced by switching the **errors reporting** to empty_img in your mapcache.xml file.

example: 
`<errors>empty_img</errors>`